# Can the Sidebar behaviour change from "push" to "overlay"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Pretty straight forward. When using the shortcut to "show/hide" the sidebar shortcut the behaviour pushes rather than overlaying the sidebar and maintaining the groups in the editor in the same place.

[Here is a scenario with the sidebar hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zql5c.png)

The goal would be that when I open the sidebar instead of the groups being flexed to the right and sharing the space with the sidebar, that instead, the sidebar simply overlays and doesn't change their positioning each time you show / hide. I have a limited real estate on my machine and am trying to get every bit I possibly can

[Like it can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQhM7.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I looked everywhere for this and it seems like it's not possible to do even with Customize UI plugins without affecting the rest of the program. You can give it a shot by launching developer tools and applying your own styles to `#workbench\.parts\.sidebar` node. The way vscode structures the view tree makes it extremely difficult to modify this behavior :|

Comment: I'm looking for the same... I needed this so much!